# where does elasticsearch store the data with default conf?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I havent configured `elasticsearch.yml`

> path.data: /path/to/data

From their website it says that version 5.0 stores everything under

> /var/lib/elasticsearch/data

However I dont even see this folder and when I go to

> /var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes/0

I see a bunch of indices that arent mine  (look like configuration indices?). Mine should start with

```
accessdata-$Timestamp
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, but ES uses the UUID for storing the indices on disk. If you do a

```
GET <indexname>/_settings
```

You will get something like this returned:

```
{
  "logstash-2017.03.13": {
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "number_of_shards": "3",
        "provided_name": "logstash-2017.03.13",
        "creation_date": "1489363199661",
        "number_of_replicas": "0",
        "uuid": "lf4NT7cURLudIfvclUCNDA",
        "version": {
          "created": "5020099"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The UUID in this case should be the folder that is in `indices/`